# Get comment list of a post - Facebook SDK for Android 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

I look at the Request.newRestRequest class but I don't know what to pass to it. There is no example which uses this method. Can you give an example for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your original rest request was `https://api.facebook.com/method/method_name?access_token=oauth_access_token&arg0=value0&arg1=value1`

Then you would do:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("arg0", "value");
b.putString("arg1", "value1");
Request r = Request.newRestRequest(session, "method_name", b, HttpMethod.GET);
```

But if you're building a new app, you should really start using the Graph API, since Facebook is in the process of deprecating the REST API as stated on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/).

Comment: i don't understand what is the method_name ?? in the document, they said it is " the method in the Facebook REST API to execute", but i don't get it >.<

Comment: All the method names are documented here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/ - but if you're writing a new app, you should really use the Graph API rather than the REST API (which is being deprecated).